# Create custom ListView from json request in mysql

Tags: android, mysql, json, listview

Hey guys i am trying to create a custom ListView in my application that loads data fdrom mysql database by json request. i used the

```
android.R.id.simple_list_item_1
```

but now i have created my own custom xml file which has 2 textviews for the name and the price.
My code is

```
public void ListDrwaer() {
        List<Map<String, String>> stocksList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

        try {
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
            JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("metoxes");
            TextView tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            TextView tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                String name = jsonChildNode.optString("name");
                String price = jsonChildNode.optString("price");
                stocksList.add(createStockList(name, price));
            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" + e.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        String[] from = { "name", "price" };
        int[] to = { R.id.textView1, R.id.textView2 };

        SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, stocksList,
                R.layout.list_item,
                from, to);
        listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
    }

    private HashMap<String, String> createStockList(String name, String price) {
        HashMap<String, String> stockNameNo = new HashMap<String, String>();
        stockNameNo.put("name", name);
        stockNameNo.put("price", price);
        return stockNameNo;
    }
```

i want to display the name of the stock in textview 1 and the price in textview 2
any help will be welcomed.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try like this

```
String[] from = { "name", "price" };
int[] to = { R.id.textView1, R.id.textView2 };

SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list,
    R.layout.list_item, from, to);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

see [this example](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#tutorial_twolistitems) for more information

Comment: but you propose android layout simple_list_item_2 and i want to use my own which is list_tem. how can i set the name for textview1 and the number for textview 2?

Comment: in the String[] from i must have "metoxes" because this is the json array that comes from database. otherwise i get an empty listview.

Comment: no need of that you have to pass arraylist of type hashmap that's it. you can follow the example which I specified

Comment: still i get an empty list view. if i do it like this
String[] from = { "metoxes", "price" };
int[] to = { R.id.textView1, R.id.textView2 };
i get the price in textview2 but only the price. with the "metoxes" i get empty list.

Comment: why you are setting text to textviews in for loop

Comment: i edited my code.in the outPut string the way it is now it displays both name and number but in textview 2. i want to display the name in textview1 and number in textview 2. but if i dont include "metoxes" in the string[] it gives me and empty list.

Comment: i finnally did it thanks to your help..i editted my code so that you can see what i was doing wrong.thanks a lot man.